# uso reduce para sumar los i (ingresados por input) del array pero los concatena y no logro que sume

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion sencilla que al ingresar números desde un input, se sumen y poder devolver el resultado, estoy usando reduce y cuando lleno yo misma el array funciona pero cuando ingreso los numeros desde el input los concantena. Como podria resolverlo? Agradezco de antemano.
dejo mi codigo:

```
 let btnNote = document.querySelector(".btn-note");
let notes = [];

btnNote.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

let input = document.querySelector(".notes-input").value;
notes.push(input);
console.log(notes);

sum();
    
})

function sum (){
    let newArray = notes.reduce((acc,el) => acc + el,0)
    console.log(newArray);
}
```

Comment: Los valores ingresados mediante elementos `input` son todos de tipo `String`, por lo cual debes hacer el `cast` adecuado si deseas realizar operaciones matemáticas con los mismos. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Esto está pasando por las reglas de la naturaleza de JavaScript, ten en cuenta que la propiedad `value` de un `<input>` es **únicamente** de tipo **string**

Y por las reglas de JS, al intentar "sumar" dos strings, el intérprete los concatenará, y esto es lo que está pasando en esta situación, basta simplemente con usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) cuando hagas el `push()` al array

```js
const btnNote = document.querySelector(".btn-note");
const notes = [];
// Usa const en vez de let, este tipo de variables no suelen cambiar su valor y se convierten en constantes

// Es una buena práctica tener definida la función antes de llamarla y no llamarla antes de definirla
function sum() {
    const newArray = notes.reduce((acc,el) => acc + el,0)
    console.log(newArray);
}

btnNote.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    let input = document.querySelector(".notes-input").value;
    notes.push(parseInt(input));
    // Usar parseInt para convertir el string a número
    console.log(notes);
    sum();
})
```